# Detection of Media Playing support in Browser

Tags: jquery, html, flash

Is there any jquery plugin on net which can detect user have installed flash player or html5 or silverlight so that I can display my video player accordingly?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery Media Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/) should handle all the heavy lifting for you, just supply your media.